# Exported OSM database do not contains node names

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I've used osm2pgrouting tool to export data from osm file to my postgresql database. Now I have database with this schema:

```
osm_node:
   -node_id
   -osm_id
   -lon
   -lat
   -numofuse
   -the_geom

osm_relations:
   -relation_id
   -type_id
   -class_id
   -name

osm_way_classes
   -class_id
   -type_id
   -name
   -priority
   -default_max_speed

osm_way_tags
   -class_id
   -way_id

osm_way_types
   -type_id
   -name

pointcloud_formats
   -pcid
   -srid
   -schema

relation_ways
   -relation_id
   -way_id
   -type

spatial_ref_sys
   -srid
   -auth_name
   -auth_srid
   -srtext
   -proj4text

ways
   -gid
   -class_id
   -length
   -length_m
   -name
   -source
   -target
   -x1
   -y1
   -x2
   -y2
   -cost
   -reverse_cost
   -cost_s
   -reverse_cost_s
   -rule
   -one_way
   -maxspeed_foward
   -maxspeed_backward
   -osm_id
   -source_osm
   -target_osm
   -priority
   -the_geom

ways_vertices_pgr
   -id
   -osm_id
   -cnt
   -cnt
   -chk
   -ein
   -eout
   -lon
   -lat
   -the_geom
```

In osm2pgrouting I use this command:

```
osm2pgrouting -f myCity.osm -c mapconfig.xml -d postgis_db -U postgres -W postgres --addnodes --clean
```

Only in table ways has some ways names ... What I do wrong or how can i get streets with numbers etc.

Comment: cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166693/how-to-export-osm-to-database-with-all-cities-and-street-names

Comment: If you mean house numbers, I'm pretty sure that OSM doesn't contain them. when you use osm2pgrouting. There is a geocoding servcice, [nominatin](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), but this involves loading using osm2pgsql.